# Bootstrap Custom Collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use bootstrap's collapse behavior in a slightly different way.
Currently.. when I have two buttons defined for Collapse operation as below..
Currently, the sequence of operation is as below.

1. Click on First button - Opens Div
2. Clck on Second button - Collapses first div (Doesnt open second div automatically)
3. I have to click on second button explicitly again to open second div.

I would like to have this process automated - Clicking on second div must collapse first div and open second div.

Could you please let me know if it is possible. Thanks.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
```

Link with href
    
    
  Button with data-target
    
    
    
    Div1
    
    
    
    
    Div2

Comment: check out this [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to acheive this using accordian after tweaking the code a little http://jsfiddle.net/Awanish/4zwv8no5/